# How to use rollup to bundle the vuejs library with my code

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I am trying to do a simple thing - I want to bundle my Javascript code (that uses vuejs) with the vue library from `node_modules` (so that the browser only loads one js file)

The files are below, **my question is** - why does the bundled js file not work while the same code works with cdn based script src links? Am I missing something in rollup?

Here is what the `body` section of my `html` looks like

```
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <!-- VUE WILL BE INJECTED HERE -->
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and here is my `main.js` file (from which bundle.js is created by rollup)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello VueREX!',
  },
});
```

and here is my `rollup.config.js`

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  plugins: [commonjs({ include: ['./main.js', './node_modules/*.*'] }),
            resolve(),],
};
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you getting a particular error?

Comment: No.  Bundle is created successfully. When I open the bundle.js file, I see the entire Vuejs code above my 3 line code. But, when I open the html file  - I see `{{ message }}` instead of 'Hello VueREX'

Comment: Are you using some type of template engine, for example, twig? Try doing `<p v-text="message"></p>` instead of `{{ message }}`.

Comment: No. No template engine. I tired with v-text instead of {{}} but nothing. If this is of any help, when I check my browser's vue-devtools, it does not detect vue at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, but I find am not sure if this is the best way

Here is what my `rollup.config.js` looks like now -

```
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';

export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  plugins: [commonjs(),
            replace({'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')}),
            alias({resolve: ['.js'], vue: __dirname + '/node_modules/vue/dist/vue'})
          ]
}
```

The `main.js` file remains as is.

Essentially, I am relying on `rollup-plugin-alias` instead of `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`

`rollup-plugin-node-resolve` works well for libraries that do not have multiple versions in the `node_modules/<lib>/dist/` directory

Comment: Worth pointing out that in Autumn 2019, `rollup-plugin-alias`, `rollup-plugin-commonjs`, and `rollup-plugin-replace` moved to `@rollup/plugin-alias`, `@rollup/plugin-plugin`, and `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` respectively.